# Correct way to execute wait-for-it script in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `wait-for-it` script added to my docker image and I execute it in my docker-compose. It works fine with this setup:

In docker-compose:

```
entrypoint: ./wait-for-it.sh mysql
```

the wait-for-it script:

```
...checks
>&2 echo "MySQL is up - executing command"
exec ../../../entrypoint.sh npm start
```

the command output when I perform `docker ps` is:

```
COMMAND
"./wait-for-it.sh ..."
```

This works fine but I don't like the 'setup'.
I want that the `wait-for-it.sh` is executed and if it succeeds I want to go to the `ENTRYPOINT` + the `CMD` of my dockerfile. I don't want to start my entrypoint hardcoded from within my wait-for-it.sh

So I changed my wait-for-it.sh script:

```
>&2 echo "MySQL is up - executing command"
exec "$@"
```

Inside my dockerfile I have:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 2368
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

How does my docker-compose.yaml needs to look to execute this in a right way after the execution of my wait-for-it script?

So I would like to get this output when I execute `docker ps`:

```
COMMAND
"/entrypoint.sh np..."
```

I tried something like this in my `docker-compose.yaml` but did not work:

```
  entrypoint: ./wait-for-it.sh mysql  /entrypoint.sh
  command: ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score -1):

you will use script like that;

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do 
    if which "$1" >/dev/null; then
        echo exists
        break
    else
        echo does not exist
        // sleep 3 seconds
        sleep 3
    fi
done
```

Comment: My script works. I do also something like `until ...'works not yet' done` and when it works it will jump to my exec. It's just the setup in the docker compose I don't really know. I'm now executing my wait-for-it as entrypoint and starting my real entrypoint hardcoded